# Why do we need startActivityForResult() method instead of just setting Parent's public variables?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Since the child activity is created by calling the startActivity(intent) from the Parent Activity, it is guaranteed that the parent object exists while the child activity is running.

From that point of view, can I just manipulate the Parent's public variables at the child's class instead of calling startActivityForResult() after I come back?

Why do we need to use the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is guaranteed that the parent object exists while the child activity is running.

No, it isn't. For starters, `startActivityForResult()` can be used across process boundaries, where the activity you are starting is in another app. The activity that is started cannot access the activity that started it, as they are in separate processes. Beyond that, it is possible that the process where the original activity resides will be terminated while it is in the background, as the user is in the second activity — this happens a fair bit when the second activity is a camera app, launched in response to something like an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`.

> can I just manipulate the Parent's public variables

One activity has no access to another activity instance. The only way that would be possible is via `static` references to activities, which are tricky to get right without introducing memory leaks. And, again, that would only work where both activities are in the same process.

> Why do we need to use the method?

You don't. There are any number of ways of writing UIs on Android. Few require the use of `startActivityForResult()`. For example, if these two bits of UI are that closely coupled, perhaps they should be in a single activity, where the bits of UI are separate fragments.